# meta_query in WP_User_Query not working - returns every user, not just users where key & value matches

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I've been going at this issue for hours now, and please save me before i go crazy.....

I'm trying to use Wordpress' WP_User_Query to retrieve users from db

I've been feeding it with arguments like this, and it works fine...:

```
function getSomeUsers ($year, $month, $day)
{
    $arg =  [

        'meta_key'      => 'some_meta_key', 
        'meta_value'    => 'some_meta_value',

        'date_query'    => [
            [   
                'year'  => $year,
                'month' => $month,
                'day'   => $day
            ]
        ] 
     ];

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $arg );

    return $user_query;
}
```

But when I try to use a meta_query instead, it returns all users in db, and not just the ones that matches the query....

```
function getSomeUsers ()
{ 
    $arg =  [
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key'     => 'some_meta_key',
                    'value'   => 'some_meta_value',
                    'compare' => '='
                ]
            ]
        ] ;

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $arg );

    return $user_query;
}
```

Anybody knows what's wrong?

edit:
I've tried the meta query on another simple wordpress site, and it works there, so there must be something else going on, meddling with the query..

I've been doing some digging with the Query Monitor plugin...
I thought it might have been because I've also been meddling with pre_user_query, but I can see that I don't have any actions attached to that hook... so nvm that...

but i can see the query being called.
This is what it looks like, and as suspected the meta keys in the meta query is not being included:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.*
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta
ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'ur_user_status' )
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt1
ON ( wp_users.ID = mt1.user_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt2
ON ( wp_users.ID = mt2.user_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( ( ( wp_usermeta.user_id IS NULL
OR ( mt1.meta_key = 'ur_user_status'
AND mt1.meta_value = '1' ) )
AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'wp_3_capabilities' ) ) )
ORDER BY user_login AS
```

It includes some weird user metadata that seems to be added by the User Registration plugin.

I deactivated the plugin, and now the meta query works.... huh

Comment: This is working for me.

Comment: hmm, i'm running a multisite.... do you know if that could have anything to do with it?

Comment: Only if the meta key is site specific. But it would still be the same key.  Have you tried using `like` for compare instead of  `=` or `exists` with no value to see if it can work at all for you?

Comment: yeah, i've tried like and using exists does the same, returns every user :/

Comment: i have suspicion that it might be because i've been messing around with pre_user_query :/ i've used `add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'add_custom_queries' )` to add some extra queries in order to order by meta data, but i've also used `remove_action( 'pre_user_query', 'add_custom_queries' )` to undo the action after making the `WP_User_Query( $arg )` call...... i might still have some actions hooked to pre_user_query..... anybody have a suggestion how to find out which actions are fired on pre_user_query ?

Comment: Use `query monitor` plugin.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion man ^_^ been doing some digging with the tool, gonna update the question with what i've found

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the meta query on another simple wordpress site, and it works there, so there must be something else going on, meddling with the query..

I've been doing some digging with the Query Monitor plugin... I thought it might have been because I've also been meddling with pre_user_query, but I can see that I don't have any actions attached to that hook... so nvm that...

but i can see the query being called. This is what it looks like, and as suspected the meta keys in the meta query is not being included:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.*
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta
ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'ur_user_status' )
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt1
ON ( wp_users.ID = mt1.user_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt2
ON ( wp_users.ID = mt2.user_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( ( ( wp_usermeta.user_id IS NULL
OR ( mt1.meta_key = 'ur_user_status'
AND mt1.meta_value = '1' ) )
AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'wp_3_capabilities' ) ) )
ORDER BY user_login AS
```

It includes some weird user metadata that seems to be added by the User Registration plugin.

I deactivated the plugin, and now the meta query works.... huh